# WCF Web API Configuration File to IIS

Tags: web-config, wcf-web-api

I have implemented a restful service with WCF Web API and I want to publish it in IIS.
During developing process I was using the service as Console Application and all configuration was made through API. 
Now I'm trying to publish the service as ASP.NET application and the only way I see is somehow to move all configuration into web config file.

Here the coded configuration:

```
var cfg = HttpHostConfiguration.Create()
                .AddMessageHandlers(typeof(AllowCrossDomainRequestHandler));

using (var host = new HttpConfigurableServiceHost(typeof(RESTfulService), cfg , new Uri("http://localhost:8081")))
            {
                var endpoint = ((HttpEndpoint)host.Description.Endpoints[0]);  //Assuming one endpoint
                endpoint.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;
                endpoint.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10;  // Allow files up to 10MB

                host.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Host opened at {0} , press any key to end", host.Description.Endpoints[0].Address);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

How should my web.config look to reflect this configuration?
Or is there any other approach instead of using ASP.NET?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve your existing config, you can put all your config set up stuff into a method, and call it from `global.asax` `Application_Start()` method. All the Global.asax methods will get called in WCF the same as they do for ASP.NET.

Or, you can wire your services to a custom `ServiceHostFactory` and `ServiceHost` that has all the configuration in it (this is the approach I am using in my current app).

Comment: ServiceHost is from WCF and not from WCF Web API right? By using ServiceHost I will lose all advantages that WCF Web API offers.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. WCF Web API provides a `WebServiceHost` flavor of ServiceHost, but it doesn't provide as much as regular WebAPI...  They sure did add some complication to an already complicated framework, didn't they? :)

Comment: They've added a simple and more organized way to create RESTful type services. WCF Web API is only Preview 4 version, I beleive this API will be improved in future. I think I will stick with hard-coded version on server side for now. Thanks, appreciate your help.